# Excel file:/// hyperlinks cause "This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer"

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Steps that cause the problem:

1. Create a new Excel document
2. Write random text in a cell
3. Right click on cell and click on Hypertext link...
4. Select "Insert into document" from the left column, select any other sheet to link to and click ok.
5. Click on the link and you get the message "This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer".

**What causes the problem and how to solve it?** Thanks.

Excel version: 2010 (14.0.7197.5000 32 bit)

OS: Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1

Comment: Is the computer part of a domain?

Comment: No it's not part of a domain. The problem happens also with http links.

Comment: ?did you solve the problem... ?how...

Comment: No, but in Excel 2016 it doesn't seem to happen.